# the difference between DTSX "Work Offline" Connection setting and DelayValidation property?

Tags: ssis

What is the difference between setting the "Work Offline" option on a Connection and setting the DelayValidation property?

Both appear to be intended to tell SSIS not to attempt to confirm the connection. I don't understand the difference....

Is it that the former prevents the Validation attenmpt and the later determines whether to reprot an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work Offline is a design consideration within Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT. Might not actually be in BIDS on a per-connection manager basis (2005/2008) as I think about that because they reworked how validation behaves with the 2012 release.

DelayValidation property is both a design and a run-time attribute for a package or its tasks and components.

They both indicate that the package should assume the meta data it last captured still remains valid. If the source for the meta data is very busy, slow to validate (some complex stored procedure sources) or is a temporary tables, either setting can be helpful.

The determination for me is based on do I want to work in a disconnected environment because it's a connectivity issue (work offline) or is a timing issue - this resource is getting created as part of the preceding step (delay validation).

Either way, the package will have to pay the price of validation. It's a matter of whether you pay it all when the package starts (and you can avoid getting a partial run "oops, truncated the table but couldn't add new data. Everything's down") or pay it on a per component basis.